# How do I toggle a displayed database field with single click

Tags: php

I have a database table and one specific value is either a value of `Yes` or `No` represented by an icon of checkmark or `X`.

[image: database display]

I want to be able to toggle this value with a single click rather then the current workflow where the user clicks the icon and then they are directed to update page where they toggle the value and then update.

[image: current update page]

The value is either Yes or No. I simply want to click it have the value change to the opposite value real time without refreshing.
Thank you

Here is the partial code for the display database, the field name is called 'enter'

```
<?php
include "db.inc.php";

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 15; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ircb ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, 15";

$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ircb"); 
$number=mysql_num_rows($query);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($rs_result)){ 

<tr bgcolor='#9B9D9F'>
<td><?= $rows['totalt'] ?></td>
       <td><?= $rows['service'] ?></td>
       <td><?= $rows['item'] ?></td>
       <td align="center">
           <a href="edit_form1.php?id=<?= $rows['id'] ?>">
               <img src="backgrounds/bg/<?= $rows['enter'] ?>.png"     border="0">
           </a>
       </td>
</tr>
```

The edit.form1

```
  <form method="post" action="update1.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo "$row[id]"?>">


   <tr>
      <td>Entered</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="enter"  
      value=Yes>Yes<input type="radio" name="enter" value=No checked>No
      </td>
    </tr>
   <hr />
    <tr style="height: 20px"><td></td></tr>
    <tr> 

      <td align="right">
        <input class="button" type="submit" 
       value="Update">
      </td>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have access to the form handling script?

Comment: form handling script?  I have seen another similar post on another site where the user  implemented                                                                                             if ($enabled == 'enabled') {
    $enabled = 'disabled';
} else {
    $enabled = 'enabled';
}
echo $enabled;

Comment: sorry not sure how to make the reply section in previous post proper format

Comment: That code is just to display the picture... Nothing to do with actually working on the database... PHP does something when receiving the form, do you have access to this script?

Comment: yes I have access to it all.  Should I post it and if so how do I properly post it here...in proper format

Comment: By editing the post mostly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having seems to be because you are redirecting to a page that has a form to do the update. Instead of using a form, you could use the link directly to do the trick. The best way to do it is to have the href lead to the exact same page that displays the table, but adding query parameters to tell the scripts to toggle the required row.

```
<a href="MY_TABLE.php?toggle_id=<?= $rows['id'] ?>"></a>
```

Using this, you could check in your PHP, before querying the database to display the tables:

```
if($_GET['toggle_id']){
    //$_GET['toggle_id'] = the ID of the line to modify
    //Use the same script as the form handler
}
```

So instead of waiting for a value of YES or NO, you would figure it out yourself using the current value:

```
 $nextValue = $currentValue=='NO'?'YES':'NO';
```

That should cover most of the logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help, makes sense to change the redirect to the current display and update with the php...not sure how to put it into play.  I assume I would create a php containing the above mentioned if($GET..